# What makes fonts in Ubuntu as sharp as fonts optimized by ClearType on Windows?

Tags: fonts, subpixel-rendering

What program or configuration is responsible for making fonts sharp and clear?

Comment: We call it Subpixel-Smoothing. See: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Subpixel_rendering

Comment: @Daniel0108, post an answer.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Both systems, Microsoft's ClearType and FreeType, use [[image] Subpixel Rendering](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Subpixel_rendering), which utilises the RGB subpixels on your TFT display to make the glyphs appear sharper and improve their form.

[image]

One important difference is that Windows tries much harder to fit the font into 'the pixel grid', which is why it looks 'sharper', at the expense of the glyphs' contours:

> ClearType also uses very heavy font hinting to force the font to fit into the pixel grid. This increases edge contrast and readability of small fonts at the expense of font rendering fidelity and has been criticised by graphic designers for making different fonts look similar. 
> <sub>from Wikipedia's [ClearType](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ClearType)</sub>

Comment: Thank you for the information summary. I like the Ubuntu method more, btw. Not just because it's open, I like it because it looks smoother and it's easier to read. Am I allowed to add your post to the http://askubuntu.com/questions/tagged/subpixel-rendering wiki?

Answer (score 2):

Posting this answer here so that I can find the answer next time when I search for "clear type ubuntu": (I hope this will help others too) 
One approach is:

1. Install Unity Tweak Tool `sudo apt-get install unity-tweak-tool`
2. run `unity-tweak-tool` in terminal (this starts the GUI)
3. Go to Fonts

   [image: Fonts]
4. Under Appearance you will find Antialiasing (none/Grayscale/RGBA).

   [image: Antialiasing in Unity Tweak Tool]

Another approach is: 
1. Install dconf editor 
2. Search for "antialiasing" 
3. If you cannot find it, the setting is under: 
org/gnome/settings-daemon/plugins/xsettings 
And there you will find the antialiasing.